# Custom Shell can not start in Win10

Tags: c#, shell, registry, kiosk, regedit

I wrote program that disbale some Win10 feature and user access for example: 
`DisableTaskmgr , fast switch , etc...`.I changed the default Shell value that was `explorer.exe` all of the change set fine, When i restart computer i get windows with out any visual so it is ok cuase i change `explorer.exe` but win10 can not run any `*.exe` app i was set on it.
i was change 2 place in registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
```

and

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
```

Additional info [Code Spinet] :

```
    string strAppPath = "C:\\MyApp\\MyApp.exe";
    RegistryKey localMachine = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);

    RegistryKey regKey = localMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", true);
    regKey.SetValue("Shell", strAppPath, RegistryValueKind.String);
    regKey.Close();
```

Comment: Can you explain how are you trying to run any exe? Is it via a command prompt as explorer is not visible anymore?

Comment: I was wrote code in .Net i add it on the original post

Comment: You are not getting my question, what I am asking is information related to testing you performed after restarting your computer. After restart of your computer, did you open a command prompt and try running an exe from there?

Comment: Sorry for delay to answer i try to check your response , i change explorer to `cmd.exe` and then call app in Command prompt it's run. no problem , also i see some article that tell to use batch file but i want to run application with out any extra interface.

Comment: [Set up a single-app kiosk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app) for Windows 10.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks but i need to do it programmatically.

Comment: Well, it's certainly possible to incorporate Powershell hosting into a program and then use that commandlet, as an example.

Comment: I noticed that in Windows 10, the ability to change the shell, except for their Microsoft signed app, was removed. i should to add some parameter for cmd.exe in shell but i don't know how can i do it ?!